# How to inject CDI bean to Message Driven Consumer

Tags: java, jms, cdi

I would like to ask how or what is the best way to implement CDI + message driven consumer. Sample codes below is the actual implementation of my application. Also, I use apache maven as the app build tool.

ITransactionService.java

```
public interface ITransactionService{
     void process();
}
```

TransactionServiceBean.java

```
@RequestScoped
@TransService
public class TransactionServiceBean implements ITransactionService{
     @Override
     public void process(){
          /logic here
     }
}
```

TransService.java

```
@Documented
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, FIELD, METHOD, PARAMETER})
@Qualifier
public @interface TransService{

}
```

JMSConsumerService.java

```
@MessageDriven
@Transactional
public class JMSConsumerService implements MessageListener {

     @Inject @TransService
     private ITransactionService transactionService;

     @Override
     public void onMessage(Message message){
          transactionService.process();
     }

}
```

When I run the application to JBoss 6.4, I get the following error in the logs and the application won't start up in the application server..

Could not resolve CDI bean for injection point

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Q: Do you have an `ITransactionService`  instance annotated with `@TransService` active in the scope?

Comment: Yes, the ITransactionService is an interface that is being implemented by my TransactionServiceBean which has an @TransService annotation at class level.. I will edit my post above..

Answer (score 0):

Why *RequestScoped*?

I think, the Request-Context will not be transported implicitly by the messages. So I can imagine, that the MessageDriven-Bean will not find an instance that can be safely used. Did you try using @*Dependent* or @*ApplicationScoped*?